# DOMNode "undefined" for xercesc on MS Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, undefined, xerces

I have started using xercesc c-3.1.1 (32-bit) on MS visual C++ 10.0.4 on Windows 7 Professional SP1.

I include

#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>

which includes

#include <xercesc/dom/DOMNode.hpp>

but when I subsequently add

```
DOMDocument*   myDocument;
DOMNode*       aNode;
DOMText*       someText;
```

to the same file, the compiler complains that DOMNode and DOMText are undefined.  I do not see why this would be since DOMNode is defined in

#include <xercesc/dom/DOMNode.hpp>

Many thanks in advance for any help,
Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add using namespace:

```
using namespace xercesc;
```

or use:

```
xercesc::DOMNode
```

etc.